# Como passar uma informação em ViewData no asp.net core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Como passar uma informação (nome do produto) do meu controller Produtos para minha view de Produtos index por ViewData?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na *controller*

```
public class ProdutosController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewData["Informacao"] = "Alguma info";
        return View();
    }
}
```

Na *view*

```
<span>
    <p>@ViewData["Informacao"]</p>
</span>
```